# Store a number of data fields in MySQL when you don't know what it will be

Tags: mysql

I wonder if anyone could offer their advice on this one.

I have some customer data whereby certain fields remain consistent. For example:

'Firstname', 'Lastname', 'Postcode'

These are the important fields and the ones that would be searched against. Over time we may have some additional data for a customer, however it is guaranteed that the fields will differ, therefore we can't indefinitely create more fields in the table to accommodate every possible new field.

I wondered what the options would be of storing the auxiliary date fields, for example would creating one additional field 'AuxData' maybe as a VARCHAR that used a JSON array? 
(I am thinking of what I have seen in wordpress in the past)

I'd really appreciate anyone's thoughts on this one!
Many thanks
JAson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an extra column with XML data, usually I would recommend JSON over XML, but MySQL has some special functionality to search trough XML data in fields. See this article for a few examples: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1019623

There is also another possibility, you could create a new table with 3 columns: [Person_ID, Property, Value] where the primary key would span (Person_ID, Property). This way you can more easily search trough data, and you keep it MySQL instead of XML/JSON. However both options are valid.

Comment: I like your second approach here. It'll be easier to work with the data if it's not buried in JSON or XML formatting. You'll have to send it to your application to figure out what it means.

Comment: Well I believe MySQL has some syntax to query inside the XML field, so that you only get info from there, but after some searching I can't find it, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you Roy, I had a look at the XML functions in MySQL, I think your second option is the one that would work best for me being able to more easily search. Thank you!